# How do I use Nokogiri and Ruby to scrape values from HTML with nested tables?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I am trying to extract the name, ID, Phone, Email, Gender, Ethnicity, DOB, Class, Major, School and GPA from a page I am parsing with Nokogiri.

I tried some different xpath's but everything I try grabs much more than I want:

```
<span class="subTitle"><b>Recruit Profile</b></span>
<br><table border="0" width="100%"><tr>
<td>
      <table bgcolor="#afafaf" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
      <table bgcolor="#cccccc" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#dddddd"><b>Name</b></td>
          <td bgcolor="#dddddd">Some Person</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#dddddd"><b>EDU ID</b></td>
          <td bgcolor="#dddddd">A12345678</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#dddddd"><b>Phone</b></td>
          <td bgcolor="#dddddd">123-456-7890</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#dddddd"><b>Address</b></td>
          <td bgcolor="#dddddd">1234 Somewhere Dr.<br>City ST, 12345</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#dddddd"><b>Email</b></td>
          <td bgcolor="#dddddd">someone@email.com</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#dddddd"><b>Gender</b></td>
          <td bgcolor="#dddddd">Female</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#dddddd"><b>Ethnicity</b></td>
          <td bgcolor="#dddddd">Unknown</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#dddddd"><b>Date of Birth</b></td>
          <td bgcolor="#dddddd">Jan 1st, 1901</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#dddddd"><b>Class</b></td>
          <td bgcolor="#dddddd">Sophomore</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#dddddd"><b>Major</b></td>
          <td bgcolor="#dddddd">Biology</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#dddddd"><b>School</b></td>
          <td bgcolor="#dddddd">University of Somewhere</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#dddddd"><b>GPA</b></td>
          <td bgcolor="#dddddd">0.00</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#dddddd" valign="top"><b>Availability</b></td>
          <td bgcolor="#dddddd">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
```

Comment: +! Excellent work including a sample of the actual HTML you need to parse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that there will be many "Recruit Profile" spans that are followed by tables that wrap up all the details. The following method takes your entire HTML page, finds just those spans, and for each of them it finds the following table and then finds the fields you want anywhere below that table:

```
require 'nokogiri'

# Pass in or set the array of labels you want to use
# Returns an array of hashes mapping these labels to the values
def recruits_details(html,fields=%W[Name #{"EDU ID"} Phone Email Gender])
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
  recruit_labels = doc.xpath('//span[b[text()="Recruit Profile"]]')
  recruit_labels.map do |recruit_label|
    recruit_table = recruit_label.at_xpath('following-sibling::table')
    Hash[ fields.map do |field_label|
      label_td = recruit_table.at_xpath(".//td[b[text()='#{field_label}']]")
      [field_label, label_td.at_xpath('following-sibling::td/text()').text ]
    end ]
  end
end

require 'pp'
pp recruits_details(html_string)
#=> [{"Name"=>"Some Person",
#=>   "EDU ID"=>"A12345678",
#=>   "Phone"=>"123-456-7890",
#=>   "Email"=>"someone@email.com",
#=>   "Gender"=>"Female"}]
```

An XPath expression like `.//foo[bar[text()="jim"]]` means:

- *Find a 'foo' element anywhere under the current node*
- *...but only if it has a 'bar' element as a child*
- *...but only if that 'bar' element has the text "jim" as its content*

An XPath expression like `following-sibling::...` means *Find any elements that are siblings after the current node that match the expression `...`*

The XPath expression `.../text()` selects the [Text node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Text.html); the `text` method is used to extract the value (actual string) of that text node.

Nokogiri's [`xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) method returns an array of all elements matching the expression, while the [`at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath) method returns the first element matching the expression.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I will get on testing this shortly!

Comment: Thank you so much, after some hacking around I got it to work perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, if you had a fan club, I would be the president.

Comment: @Sean :) Glad to have helped.